# Is it safe to cloud sync TFS workspaces?

Tags: version-control, tfs, cloud, synchronization

Please excuse a newbie question, but I've always used SVN and more recently, Git. Just now am touching TFS for the first time.

If I have two different machines that I work on regularly, can I safely keep the project files in sync using something like Dropbox/Sugarsync/Skydrive?

Are there any pros/cons to be aware of?

(I know that some of you might ask something like why not just checkout on the other machine. Just trying to save a step. I want to just pick up the other machine and do what I need to do without having to check out anything.)

Answer (score 0):

TFS workspaces contain information about the machine name and user that created them, however if you're using local workspaces and you're not putting any server-side locks on files then I suppose you could sync them via dropbox and it should probably work just fine.

**That said, I'd never recommend it.**

You're not only going to sync all your code but also all the binaries that you're producing each and every time you compile, plus you won't have any change history between machines and you need to keep monitoring the drop box app to make sure things have synced fully before switching machines.

If you want to move changes between two machines I'd recommend using shelvesets. It only takes a few seconds to do and you'll have a more explicit update process between machines. You can be sure of what is happening in your code on each machine and you have an implicit rollback point if you realise you put something in the shelveset you didn't want.